# MySQL query code using the OR for two different fields with Web Service

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, web-services

Normally I can figure this out, but the format looks a bit different then what I am used to. I have a web service using php with CodeIgnighter. The function looks like this:

```
    function getCurrentSales($office_id)
    {
        $CI =& get_instance();
        $CI->load->model("properties");

        //Get the properties
        $where = array('field_SaleOfficeCode'=>$office_id);
        $where = array('field_ListOfficeCode'=>$office_id);
        $result = $CI->properties->getCurrentSales($where); 
        $properties = $result->result_array();

        foreach($properties as $p){
            //Get property images
            $where = array('ListingKey'=>$p['UniqueKey']);
            $property_arr[] = $p;
        }   

            return  $property_arr;
    }

    $this->nusoap_server->service(file_get_contents("php://input"));
}
```

What I am trying to do is return rows where `field_ListOfficeCode` or `field_ListOfficeCode` have the value of `$office_id`. As it is now, only when `field_ListOfficeCode=>$office_id`, not when one or the other equals the value.

Models Method Code:

```
function getCurrentSales($where = null) {


    $this->db->select('field_ListingKey as UniqueKey,
                        field_LocaleListingStatus as Status,
                        field_CloseDate as ClosingDate,
                        field_ContractDate as ContractDate,
                        field_ListingID as MLS,
                        TRIM("#VARIES" from field_FullStreetAddress) as StreetAddress,
                        field_ListPrice as Price,
                        field_ListOfficeCode as BrokerID,
                        if(field_Beds != "", field_Beds, 0) as NumBeds,
                        if(field_BathsFull != "", field_BathsFull, 0) as NumFullBaths,
                        if(field_BathsHalf != "", field_BathsHalf, 0) as NumHalfBaths,
                        field_InternetRemarks as PropertyRemarks,
                        field_ListOfficeName as ListingOfficeName,
                        field_ListPicture3URL as MainPhoto,
                        CONCAT(field_ListAgentNickname, " ", field_ListAgentLastName, " ", (if(field_ListAgentNameSuffix = "NULL", field_ListAgentNameSuffix, ""))) as ListingAgent,
                        CONCAT(field_SaleAgentNickname, " ", field_SaleAgentLastName, " ", (if(field_SaleAgentNameSuffix = "NULL", field_SaleAgentNameSuffix, ""))) as SalesAgent,
                        CONCAT(field_City, ", ", field_State, " ", field_PostalCode) as AreaAddress', false);


    $this->db->from('TABLE_2');



    if($where != null){
        $this->db->where($where, false);
        $this->db->where('YEAR(field_ContractDate) = YEAR(NOW())', NULL, false);
        $this->db->where('MONTH(field_ContractDate) = MONTH(NOW())', NULL, false);
    }


    $this->db->order_by('ContractDate', 'desc'); //get random row
    //$this->db->limit($limit);


    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query;     
}
```

Comment: Can you add the code from the Models method getCurrentSales

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with CodeIgniter, but I would suspect your problem is with these two lines

```
$where = array('field_SaleOfficeCode'=>$office_id);
$where = array('field_ListOfficeCode'=>$office_id);
```

You aren't actually building up an array of where clauses, but rather overriding the first assignment with the second, which explains why you are only getting results that match `field_ListOfficeCode == $office_id`

Depending on how CodeIgniter expects these where clauses to be formed, I would assume it should be something like

```
$where = array(
    array('field_SaleOfficeCode'=>$office_id),
    array('field_ListOfficeCode'=>$office_id)
)
```

Or from a quick look at [the documentation](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html)

```
$where = array(
    'field_SaleOfficeCode'=>$office_id,
    'field_ListOfficeCode'=>$office_id
)
```

And then in your `getCurrentSales` function, it should be

```
$this->db->or_where($where)
```

Comment: I will give it a try and let you know how it goes. Thank you.

Comment: No Joy, but I am glad you showed me that page. I looked all over for it  as I have seen it before and I could not find it. Thanks!

Comment: Well I'm glad I could at least help out in some small way.

Comment: Every bit counts. I have struggled trying to find the right combination. I will get it at some point, Hopefully I will not pull the last piece of hair out before I do. :^)